# Object order changes after reducer updates the state

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

Currently I'm learning Redux, playing around with different stuff.
So I made a simple TODO app with possibility to edit each TODO item.

But for some reason UPDATE_TODO reducer puts the updated TODO item at the and of the list. So the item is successfully updated but it jumps to the end of TODO's list, instead of staying at the original position.

Original TODO items positioning:

- item 1 <-- being updated
- item 2
- item 3

Positioning after updating of *item 1*:

- item 2
- item 3
- item 1 <-- was updated

In my reducer I filter all TODOs except updated one with filter() and then set a new state for the updated TODO item.

**Need an advice how to update TODO item state properly so it remains at the original position?**

reducers

```
import { UPDATE_TODO } from '../constants';

const initialState = {
  all: [] // array of all TODO's
}

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    ...
    case UPDATE_TODO:
      return {
        ...state,
        all: [
          ...state.all.filter(todo => todo.id !== action.payload.id),
          action.payload
        ]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are putting the updated item `action.payload` in the last:

```
all: [
    ...state.all.filter(todo => todo.id !== action.payload.id),
    action.payload
]
```

Here `filter` will return all the todo items other than the updated one, then after all the items you are putting the `action.payload` (the updated one).

Instead of that use `map` and put the condition, when `todo.id == action.payload.id` will be `true` then return the updated one otherwise return the existing items.

Like this:

```
case UPDATE_TODO:
    return {
        ...state,
        all: [
            ...state.all.map(todo => {
                if(todo.id == action.payload.id)
                    return action.payload;
                return todo;
            })              
        ]
};
```